# How to check that certain datetime is in between the adjacent row dates?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I have the following table column values:

```
2013-06-28T13:00:00.000Z    Motion
2013-06-28T18:15:00.000Z    Static  (row2)
2013-07-03T13:57:22.000Z    Moving  (row3)
2013-07-03T13:59:00.000Z    Motion
```

I want to check if dates `29-06-2013T01:00:00Z` and `29-06-2013T05:00:00Z` are both **Static**. Similarly, I want to check for dates `30-06-2013T01:00:00Z` and `30-06-2013T05:00:00Z`.
Obviously this is true if we consider the above table values because both the dates are between row2 and row3.

How to do that with sqlite ?

I am getting the dates `29-06-2013` and `30-06-2013`. So first I need to set times 1am and 5am to both of these dates and then check if they both are **Static**.

I tried the following:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(input1.parse(startDate.get(0))); //29-06-2013
cal1.add(Calendar.AM, 1); //Added 1am to date 29-06-2013
weekHours = cal1.getTime(); 

Cursor chkCur1 = dbAdapter.rawQuery("select movement from user where Date <= '"
    + input1.format(weekHours) + "' order by Date asc LIMIT 1", null);

chkCur1.moveToFirst();

if(!chkCur1.isAfterLast() && chkCur1.getString(0).equals("Static"))
{
cal1.add(Calendar.AM, 5); //Added 5am to date 29-06-2013
weekHours = cal1.getTime();
}

chkCur1 = dbAdapter.rawQuery("select movement from user where Date <= '"
    + input1.format(weekHours) + "' order by Date asc LIMIT 1", null);

chkCur1.moveToFirst();

if(!chkCur1.isAfterLast() && chkCur1.getString(0).equals("Static")){
cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal1.add(Calendar.AM, 1); //Added 1am to date 30-06-2013
weekHours = cal1.getTime();


}

chkCur1 = dbAdapter.rawQuery("select movement from user where Date <= '"
    + input1.format(weekHours) + "' order by Date asc LIMIT 1", null);

chkCur1.moveToFirst();

if(!chkCur1.isAfterLast() && chkCur1.getString(0).equals("Static")){
cal1.add(Calendar.AM, 5); //Added 5am to date 30-06-2013
weekHours = cal1.getTime();

}

chkCur1 = dbAdapter.rawQuery("select movement from user where Date <= '"
    + input1.format(weekHours) + "' order by Date asc LIMIT 1", null);

chkCur1.moveToFirst();

if(!chkCur1.isAfterLast() && chkCur1.getString(0).equals("Static")){
System.out.println("Both dates are in between")
}
```

I used 4 sql queries:

**1)** Setting time `1am` to date1 and check if its previous is Static.

**2)** Setting time `5am` to date1 and check if its previous is Static.

**3)** Setting time `1am` to date2 and check if its previous is Static.

**4)** Setting time `5am` to date2 and check if its previous is Static.

If all conditions satisfies then both dates (date1 and date2) are in between i.e. Static.

But this is the repeat of sql queries and thus slowing down the process.

Comment: Why don't you just fetch a list once and then run the checks on the list

Comment: I fetched the list once and got the dates `29-06-2013` and `30-6-2013` but now I want to check the previous which again needs the sql checks. Is there in between ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all the four checks into subqueries:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT movement FROM user WHERE Date <= ? ORDER BY Date) = 'Static'
   AND (SELECT movement FROM user WHERE Date <= ? ORDER BY Date) = 'Static'
   AND (SELECT movement FROM user WHERE Date <= ? ORDER BY Date) = 'Static'
   AND (SELECT movement FROM user WHERE Date <= ? ORDER BY Date) = 'Static';
```

This will give you a single result record with a single boolean column.